# Are there people who can change one of their eyes' depth of focus, while not changing the other eye's?

Tags: human-biology, vision, eyes, human-eye

Are there people who can change one of their eyes' depth of focus, while not changing the other eye's depth of focus, without any surgical or other external mechanical intervention?

Edit: let's assume both eyes are functional and not obstructed.

Comment: Have to tried to find an answer to your question, please share as queries with low or no effort are off-topic in Biology SE?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker doesn't show any attempt at an answer.

Comment: What is the fun people have in closing questions? You can also just let it rot away in silence. What is the important difference?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, Stack Exchange started as [Stack Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) with the aim to build an **open access** online library of **good (quality) questions and answers** on computer programming. So to maintain the quality of the site these measures; downvoting,editing, flagging and closing others' posts have been implemented. About why not leave questions with low effort open? [...]

Comment: [...] Well, just to maintain the quality. Leaving them open would mean questions the site wants to discourage (low effort/ unclear/ opinion-based / too broad) are being entertained. Mostly questions are answered by biologists here (and concerned experts in other  communities) who donate their time to help others **find** an answer, this just ensures that they are not spoon feeding the asker which disinterest them and anybody who wishes to take up the challenge of answering good questions. Our help page can be found [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).